# Is it OK to skip redrawing a WebGL canvas in a requestAnimationFrame callback?

Tags: requestanimationframe

In a game I'm writing I want to provide an option to slow down the frame rate so users can trade off smoothness against battery life. The content is basically just a WebGL canvas. I think the most practical way to reduce the frame rate is to still chain requestAnimationFrame calls as usual, but only do any actual rendering every 2 or 3 frames. But will that work properly? Is it guaranteed that browsers realise when the canvas hasn't actually been updated and avoid swapping the GPU framebuffer in that case, or am I at risk of swapping to a "stale" frame from my last-but-one update due to double-buffering?